# Spectral decomposition of Rodrigues' rotation formula

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory

I am supposed to rewrite Rodrigues' rotation formula

$R(v)=v\cos \phi+k(k\cdot v)(1-\cos\phi)+(k\times v)\sin\phi$

in the form of spectral decomposition. I can figure out that the eigenvalues are 1, $e^{i\phi}$, $e^{-i\phi}$ and the eigenvector belonging to 1 is k, so we have

$R=kk^T+e^{i\phi}v_+v_+^T+e^{-i\phi}v_-v_-^T$ ,

but I'm not sure how to find the other eigenvectors $v_\pm$ without explicitly calculating $\mathrm{Ker}(R-\lambda I)$ from the matrix form. Is there a more elegant, painless way how to solve this? Or maybe I should choose a different approach altogether? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rodrigues' rotation formula is completely irrelevant to this problem. It is simply a clever way of writing down the action of the operator $R(\phi,k)$, which I will use to denote rotation by angle $\phi$ about axis $k$. Given that's the case, all you're really doing is writing down the spectral decomposition of a rotation matrix.

Since $k$ is the axis, it also serves as one of the eigenvectors. Let $u_1$ and $u_2$ denote any orthonormal basis for the plane orthogonal to $k$, oriented so that $u_1 \times u_2 = k$, i.e., such that $R(\pi/2,k)u_1 = u_2$ and $R(\pi/2,k)u_2 = -u_1$. Then the other two eigenvectors are
$$v_{\pm} = (u_1 \pm iu_2)/\sqrt{2}.$$
All of this just follows from the familiar spectral decomposition of the rotation matrix
$$R(\phi) = \begin{pmatrix}\cos\phi & -\sin\phi \\ \sin\phi & \cos\phi\end{pmatrix}.$$

**Edit:** It might be instructive to see how this spectral decomposition is related to the Rodrigues' formula itself. Let
$$R = kk^\dagger + e^{i\phi}v_+v_+^\dagger + e^{-i\phi}v_{-}v_{-}^\dagger$$
be the spectral decomposition as outlined above. I use daggers to indicate Hermitian conjugation. Let me expand everything out in terms of sines, cosines, and the orthonormal basis $\{k,u_1,u_2\}$. Doing so, we get
$$R = kk^\dagger + (u_1u_1^\dagger + u_2u_2^\dagger)\cos\phi + (u_1u_2^\dagger - u_2u_1^\dagger)\sin\phi.$$
Matching the individual terms to Rodrigues' formula, we see that the $kk^\dagger$ term is responsible for $k(k\cdot v)$ through the action
$$kk^\dagger v = k(k\cdot v).$$
The $(u_1u_1^\dagger + u_2u_2^\dagger)\cos\phi$ is responsible for the $(v - k(k\cdot v))\cos\phi$ term through the resolution of the identity:
$$kk^\dagger + u_1u_1^\dagger + u_2u_2^\dagger = I.$$
Through this we get
$$(u_1u_1^\dagger + u_2u_2^\dagger)v\cos\phi = (I - kk^\dagger)v\cos\phi = (v - k(k\cdot v))\cos\phi.$$
The final term $(u_1u_2^\dagger - u_2u_1^\dagger)\sin\phi$ is responsible for the $(k\times v)\sin\phi$. This is a bit trickier to show, and it amounts to showing that the matrix $[k]_\times\equiv u_1u_2^\dagger - u_2u_1^\dagger$ is a representation of the cross-product, i.e., for any vector $v$, we have $[k]_\times v = k\times v$.

You can verify this through a direct basis calculation. Alternatively, if you know a little bit about the representation theory of $SO(3)$, you can use the fact that the action of the cross-product is the infinitesimal generator of rotations (i.e., the adjoint representation of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$). Through this, we get
$$\frac{d}{d\phi}\bigg|_{\phi=0}R(\phi,k) = [k]_\times.$$
Using our spectral resolution, this is
$$\frac{d}{d\phi}\bigg|_{\phi=0}R(\phi,k) = i(v_+v_+^\dagger - v_{-}v_{-}^\dagger) = u_1u_2^\dagger - u_2u_1^\dagger.$$
Putting all of this together, we get the final term as
$$(u_1u_2^\dagger - u_2u_1^\dagger)v\sin\phi = [k]_\times v\sin\phi = (k\times v)\sin\phi.$$
This gives you the precise relation of the spectral resolution to the Rodrigues' formula.

**Edit 2:** To see that the other two eigenvectors are $v_{\pm}$ given by $(u_1\pm iu_2)/\sqrt{2}$, it suffices to work in a basis (the $\sqrt{2}$s are just so the vectors are normalized). Since we know one of our eigenvectors is $k$, so let's pick the ordered orthonormal basis $\{u_1,u_2,k\}$, where $u_1$ and $u_2$ are defined and oriented as before.

In this basis, the rotation matrix is given by
$$R(\phi,k) = \begin{pmatrix}\cos\phi & -\sin\phi & 0\\ \sin\phi & \cos\phi & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$
A quick calculation shows you that the remaining eigenvectors $v_{\pm}$ are given in this basis by
$$v_+ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1\\i\\0\end{pmatrix}, \qquad\text{and}\qquad v_+ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1\\-i\\0\end{pmatrix}. $$
This corresponds to
$$v_{\pm} = (u_1 \pm iu_2)/\sqrt{2},$$
as before.

Comment: So to explicitly compute it, next I need to pick $u_1$,  $u_2$ and express them in terms of the components of $k=(k_1, k_2,k_3)$, calculate $v_\pm$ and then $v_\pm v_\pm^\dagger$, correct?

Comment: If you want a very explicit formula for the spectral decomposition, that would be one way to do it. You can pick any solution of the equation $u_1\cdot k = 0$ and take $u_2 = k\times u_1$. This choice will not be canonical, since you can pick any solution for $u_1$, however the spectral decomposition itself will be unique, and it will in fact reduce down to the Rodrigues formula itself (this is in fact one way of deriving the Rodrigues formula, see my edit).

Comment: Thank you for a comprehensive answer. If you have the time could you please also comment on how to arrive at the fact that $v_{\pm} = (u_1 \pm iu_2)/\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: It's easiest to work in a basis for this calculation, but by choosing the basis nicely, i.e., in a way that respects the rotation, the actual calculation part is minimal. If you know the eigenvectors of a $2\times 2$ rotation, you can probably do this in your head. In any case, I've added an edit to the answer.

Comment: One last thing I hope: In that case shouldn't the signs be switched? $v_+=1/\sqrt2(1,-i,0)$ corresponds to the eigenvalue $e^{i\pi}$ so shouldn't it be $v_{\pm} = (u_1 \mp iu_2)/\sqrt{2}$ ?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I was doing this from memory and I got the signs mixed up. You are right. Luckily nothing about the argument changes, up to a few sign corrections.